# Install problem for xdotool

Tags: terminal, software-installation, kali-linux, xdotool

Since I have problems with my Internet connection I'm not able to always run command
 `apt-get install xdotool` in Terminal, so I would like to download the **xdotool** package manually from website in .zip or .deb format and then install it manually every time I need it. (I'm using Usb Live Kali Linux 2016.2-amd64 and every time I reboot it deletes all files).

I've tried to download xdotool from https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool at the right side in green box "Clone or download" there is option download ZIP. After that I extract all files in Home folder and then open it in Terminal.
in README file there are instructions like this:

> See the website for more up-to-date documentation
>   http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/   or the manpage listed
>   below.
>
> Compile: make
>   Install: make install
>   Remove: make uninstall
>
> You may have to set 'PREFIX' to the location you want to install to. 
>   The default PREFIX is /usr/local
>
> For packagers, there's also support for DESTDIR for staged install.

I type in `make` then `make install` and it always outputs me this error:

```
    root@kali:~/xdotool-master# make
cc -pipe -O2 -pedantic -Wall -W -Wundef -Wendif-labels -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wdisabled-optimization -Wno-missing-field-initializers -g    -std=c99 -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/local/include -fPIC -c xdo.c
xdo.c:29:34: fatal error: X11/extensions/XTest.h: No such file or directory
 #include <X11/extensions/XTest.h>
                                  ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:124: recipe for target 'xdo.o' failed
make: *** [xdo.o] Error 1  


root@kali:~/xdotool-master# make install
install -d /usr/local
cc -pipe -O2 -pedantic -Wall -W -Wundef -Wendif-labels -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wdisabled-optimization -Wno-missing-field-initializers -g    -std=c99 -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/local/include -fPIC -c xdo.c
xdo.c:29:34: fatal error: X11/extensions/XTest.h: No such file or directory
 #include <X11/extensions/XTest.h>
                                  ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:124: recipe for target 'xdo.o' failed
make: *** [xdo.o] Error 1
root@kali:~/xdotool-master#
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Can you suggest me other methods of installation of xdotool (but without Internet connection)?

Comment: Did you run `make` before `make install`? You are also likely to need development packages to compile.

Comment: ALSO, read up about persistent storage for live mediums. It looks like the real game changer for your issue

Comment: @Bruno9779 for first comment I edited my question above. For second comment, I know for persistence and already tried different tutorials and none of them unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: Why do you download the source code and try to compile it, instead of downloading the binary `.deb` (the one `apt-get install xdotool` would also fetch and install, without compiling)?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting says that you miss the file XTest.h.

Look up which package provides it with (on debian derivates):

```
dpkg -S Xtest.h
```

The package should be `libXtst-dev`, you might need to add some repositories, if the command doesn't return anything